# Window functions and more "local" aggregation

Tags: postgresql, common-table-expression, window-functions

Suppose I have this table:

```
select * from window_test;

 k | v
---+---
 a | 1
 a | 2
 b | 3
 a | 4
```

Ultimately I want to get:

```
 k | min_v | max_v
---+-------+-------
 a | 1     | 2
 b | 3     | 3
 a | 4     | 4
```

But I would be just as happy to get this (since I can easily filter it with `distinct`):

```
 k | min_v | max_v
---+-------+-------
 a | 1     | 2
 a | 1     | 2
 b | 3     | 3
 a | 4     | 4
```

Is it possible to achieve this with PostgreSQL 9.1+ window functions? I'm trying to understand if I can get it to use separate partition for the first and last occurrence of `k=a` in this sample (ordered by `v`).

Comment: First: Do you want to "collapse" complete ranges? I.e. what would you expect when you add `(a,5), (a,6), (a,7)` to your data set? Second: Is `v` always perfectly increasing by 1 or can there be gaps?

Comment: @A.H. `v` is not perfectly increasing (in fact, it's a timestamp). Yes, I want to collapse complete ranges and would expect `(a, 4, 5)` as the last tuple after inserting `(a, 5)`.

Comment: @KonradGarus, does any of the provided solutions works for you?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This returns your desired result with the sample data. Not sure if it will work for real world data:

```
select k, 
       min(v) over (partition by group_nr) as min_v,
       max(v) over (partition by group_nr) as max_v
from (
    select *,
           sum(group_flag) over (order by v,k) as group_nr
    from (
    select *,
           case
              when lag(k) over (order by v) = k then null
              else 1
            end as group_flag
    from window_test
    ) t1
) t2
order by min_v;
```

I left out the `DISTINCT` though.

Comment: Thanks guys. I like both solutions, but find this one more elegant.

Comment: Nice work there, but it was not working for me (postgresql 9.3) until I added the `group by k, group_nr` sentence before the `order by min_v`, and replaced the `min(v) over...` and `max(v) over...` window functions in the main select for simple aggregate `min(v)` and `max(v)` functions. Thanks, this really helped me:)

Answer (score 1):

**EDIT:** I've came up with the following query — without window functions at all:

```sql
WITH RECURSIVE tree AS (
  SELECT k, v, ''::text as next_k, 0 as next_v, 0 AS level FROM window_test
  UNION ALL
  SELECT c.k, c.v, t.k, t.v + level, t.level + 1
    FROM tree t JOIN window_test c ON c.k = t.k AND c.v + 1 = t.v),
partitions AS (
  SELECT t.k, t.v, t.next_k,
         coalesce(nullif(t.next_v, 0), t.v) AS next_v, t.level
    FROM tree t
   WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM tree WHERE next_k = t.k AND next_v = t.v))
SELECT min(k) AS k, v AS min_v, max(next_v) AS max_v
  FROM partitions p
 GROUP BY v
 ORDER BY 2;
```

I've provided 2 working queries now, I hope one of them will suite you.

[SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/f7076/1) for this variant.

---

Another way how to achieve this is to use a support sequence.

1. Create a support sequence:

   ```
   CREATE SEQUENCE wt_rank START WITH 1;
   ```
2. The query:

   ```
   WITH source AS (
     SELECT k, v,
            coalesce(lag(k) OVER (ORDER BY v), k) AS prev_k
       FROM window_test
       CROSS JOIN (SELECT setval('wt_rank', 1)) AS ri),
   ranking AS (
     SELECT k, v, prev_k,
            CASE WHEN k = prev_k THEN currval('wt_rank')
                 ELSE nextval('wt_rank') END AS rank
       FROM source)
   SELECT r.k, min(s.v) AS min_v, max(s.v) AS max_v
       FROM ranking r
       JOIN source s ON r.v = s.v
      GROUP BY r.rank, r.k
      ORDER BY 2;
   ```

Comment: Thanks. Actually, `v` is the sorting column. This solution breaks if I add (a, 5) tuple at the end (in other words, if there are a few clusters with more than one row each).

Answer (score 0):

Would this not do the job for you, without the need for windows, partitions or coalescing. It just uses a traditional SQL trick for finding nearest tuples via a self join, and a min on the difference:

```
SELECT k, min(v), max(v) FROM (
    SELECT k, v, v + min(d) lim FROM (
        SELECT x.*, y.k n, y.v - x.v d FROM window_test x
        LEFT JOIN window_test y ON x.k <> y.k AND y.v - x.v > 0) 
    z GROUP BY k, v, n)
w GROUP BY k, lim ORDER BY 2;
```

I think this is probably a more 'relational' solution, but I'm not sure about its efficiency.

Comment: The solution with a window function is typically faster. Your query needs to go through the `window_test` table twice (because of the self-join). A join using `<` or `>` usually doesn't scale either. Plus: you are grouping the result of the join which means more rows need to be processed by the group by then with the window function (which only needs to deal with the rows in table once). But what's wrong with window functions? Every modern DBMS supports them.

Comment: Agreed. And certainly nothing against window functions - I offer this solution to the OP as it might be of interest in that it only using operators from relational algebra, and hence might be considered 'purer' (I personally think it is clearer conceptually too).  However, I wouldn't use it on a billion row relation...