# Collapse multiple rows having contiguous timestamps

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a table that represents usage of a product, kind of like a log. Product usage is logged as multiple timestamps, I want to represent the same data using time ranges.

It looks like this (PostgreSQL 9.1):

```
userid | timestamp          | product
-------------------------------------
001    | 2012-04-23 9:12:05 | foo
001    | 2012-04-23 9:12:07 | foo
001    | 2012-04-23 9:12:09 | foo
001    | 2012-04-23 9:12:11 | barbaz
001    | 2012-04-23 9:12:13 | barbaz
001    | 2012-04-23 9:15:00 | barbaz
001    | 2012-04-23 9:15:01 | barbaz
002    | 2012-04-24 3:41:01 | foo
002    | 2012-04-24 3:41:03 | foo
```

I want to collapse rows whose time difference with the previous run is less than a *delta* (say: *2 seconds*), and get the begin time and the end time, like this:

```
userid | begin              | end                | product
----------------------------------------------------------
001    | 2012-04-23 9:12:05 | 2012-04-23 9:12:09 | foo
001    | 2012-04-23 9:12:11 | 2012-04-23 9:12:13 | barbaz
001    | 2012-04-23 9:15:00 | 2012-04-23 9:15:01 | barbaz
002    | 2012-04-24 3:41:01 | 2012-04-24 3:41:03 | foo
```

Please note that consecutive usage of the same product is split into two rows if their usage is more than *delta* (2 seconds, in this example) apart.

```
create table t (userid int, timestamp timestamp, product text);

insert into t (userid, timestamp, product) values 
(001, '2012-04-23 9:12:05', 'foo'),
(001, '2012-04-23 9:12:07', 'foo'),
(001, '2012-04-23 9:12:09', 'foo'),
(001, '2012-04-23 9:12:11', 'barbaz'),
(001, '2012-04-23 9:12:13', 'barbaz'),
(001, '2012-04-23 9:15:00', 'barbaz'),
(001, '2012-04-23 9:15:01', 'barbaz'),
(002, '2012-04-24 3:41:01', 'foo'),
(002, '2012-04-24 3:41:03', 'foo')
;
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Inspired by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10624628/1154462), given a while back by @a_horse_with_no_name.

```sql
WITH groupped_t AS (
SELECT *, sum(grp_id) OVER (ORDER BY userid,product,"timestamp") AS grp_nr
  FROM (SELECT t.*,
          lag("timestamp") OVER
           (PARTITION BY userid,product ORDER BY "timestamp") AS prev_ts,
          CASE WHEN ("timestamp" - lag("timestamp") OVER
            (PARTITION BY userid,product ORDER BY "timestamp")) <= '2s'::interval
          THEN NULL ELSE 1 END AS grp_id
        FROM t) AS g
), periods AS (
SELECT min(gt."timestamp") AS grp_min, max(gt."timestamp") AS grp_max, grp_nr
  FROM groupped_t AS gt
 GROUP BY gt.grp_nr
)
SELECT gt.userid, p.grp_min AS "begin", p.grp_max AS "end", gt.product
  FROM periods p
  JOIN groupped_t gt ON gt.grp_nr = p.grp_nr AND gt."timestamp" = p.grp_min
 ORDER BY gt.userid, p.grp_min;
```

1. The innermost query will assign groupping IDs based on the `userid`, `product` and time difference. I assumed it should be safe to `PARTITION BY` first two fields in fact.
2. `groupped_t` gives me all the source columns + an extra running group number. I used only `ORDER BY` here for the `sum()` window function, as I need group IDs to be unique.
3. `periods` is just a helper query for the first and last timestamp in each group.
4. Finally, I join `groupped_t` with `periods` on the `grp_nr` (that's why I needed it to be unique) and a timestamp of the first entry in each group.

You can also check this query on [SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!1/551dc/1).

Note, that `timestamp`, `begin` and `end` are [reserved words in the SQL](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-keywords-appendix.html) (`end` also for PostgreSQL), so you should either avoid or double-quote them.

Comment: I really liked the way you used 1 and null to group the registers together! I was struggling with this, trying with 0 and 1... how come a simple twist like that can change so much, right? Awesome, thanks!