# Time series in PostgreSQL - list changes

Tags: postgresql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

I have a table in PostgreSQL with some time-series data, showing the changes of values in a parameter - we can assume there is no gap and that each `date_to` has a corresponding `date_from` (except the last one of course):

```
select date_from, date_to, xx from yy order by date_from asc;

date_from  |  date_to   |               xx
-----------+------------+------------------
2014-05-01 | 2014-05-21 |                0
2014-05-21 | 2014-06-02 |               10
2014-06-02 | 2014-06-05 |               10
2014-06-05 | 2014-06-10 |               10
2014-06-10 | 2014-06-26 |                0
2014-06-26 | 2014-07-01 |               10
2014-07-01 | 2014-07-08 |               10
2014-07-08 | 2014-07-23 |                0
2014-07-23 | 2014-08-04 |               10
2014-08-04 | 2014-08-20 |               10
2014-08-20 | 2014-09-02 |               20
2014-09-02 | 2014-09-03 |               20
2014-09-03 | 2014-09-22 |                0
2014-09-22 | 2014-09-24 |               10
2014-09-24 | 2014-10-02 |               20
2014-10-02 | 2014-10-08 |               20
2014-10-08 | infinity   |                0
```

My goal is to aggregate the data by time intervals, and show during which time periods `xx` stayed at a given value:

```
date_from  |  date_to   |               xx
-----------+------------+------------------
2014-05-01 | 2014-05-21 |                0
2014-05-21 | 2014-06-10 |               10
2014-06-10 | 2014-06-26 |                0
2014-06-26 | 2014-07-08 |               10
2014-07-08 | 2014-07-23 |                0
2014-07-23 | 2014-08-20 |               10
2014-08-20 | 2014-09-03 |               20
2014-09-03 | 2014-09-22 |                0
2014-09-22 | 2014-09-24 |               10
2014-09-24 | 2014-10-08 |               20
2014-10-08 | infinity   |                0
```

In order to present this data in a more compact way to some business users, I tried using [window functions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/tutorial-window.html) but I didn't find how to isolate those changes. Does anyone have a hint there?

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use running total feature to create group identifiers, like this:

```
WITH yy(date_from,date_to,xx) AS (
  VALUES ('2014-05-01'::date,'2014-05-21'::date,0),
    ('2014-05-21','2014-06-02',10),
    ('2014-06-02','2014-06-05',10),
    ('2014-06-05','2014-06-10',10),
    ('2014-06-10','2014-06-26',0),
    ('2014-06-26','2014-07-01',10),
    ('2014-07-01','2014-07-08',10),
    ('2014-07-08','2014-07-23',0),
    ('2014-07-23','2014-08-04',10),
    ('2014-08-04','2014-08-20',10),
    ('2014-08-20','2014-09-02',20),
    ('2014-09-02','2014-09-03',20),
    ('2014-09-03','2014-09-22',0),
    ('2014-09-22','2014-09-24',10),
    ('2014-09-24','2014-10-02',20),
    ('2014-10-02','2014-10-08',20),
    ('2014-10-08','infinity',0)
)
SELECT date_from,date_to,xx,
       sum(g) OVER (ORDER BY date_from) grp
  FROM (
    SELECT date_from,date_to,xx,
           CASE WHEN lag(xx) OVER (ORDER BY date_from) = xx THEN NULL ELSE 1 END g
      FROM yy) s
 ORDER BY date_from;
```

As soon as you have new column `grp`, you can use it to `GROUP BY`.
Note, that subqueries are needed here, as one cannot refer to the results of the window functions otherwise.

Please, check also this [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614505/window-functions-and-more-local-aggregation).